# Swift syntax issue: var a:Int64 = -7

Tags: swift, syntax, variable-assignment

I'm playing with Apple's new Swift language. Below snippet can successfully produce a result:

```
var a:Int64 = -7
println(a)
```

However, if I change the code to this:

```
var a:Int64 =-7
println(a)
```

I'll get the error:

> Error:(12, 12) consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

It seems that Swift thinks `=-` is an operator, which does not exist in Swift. If so, why generate that error?

Answer (score 2):

Swift is very strict to avoid ambiguity in operators `=-` in `var a:Int64 =-7` basically means unary prefix operator, that is undefined in this case. The `=-` cannot be split in two as there is no separator and `=-` operator can be defined any time. To avoid any ambiguity use spaces. `var a:Int64 = -7` has clear separation between assignment and unary prefix operator.